Can you integrate a function if it has a digamma function in it.
I was trying to find a better approximation than $\operatorname{li}(x)$ for the prime counting function. Now, I'm trying to get an approximate formula for the nth prime out of it. I need to find an expanded form for the integral below to solve for the nth prime. I've tried the Feynman technique for integration and integration by parts. Nothing is working. Wolfram Alpha also does not give a solution. Can anyone expand it in a way that I can take its inverse to make a formula out of?
$$\int{\frac{x\Psi(x+1)-\ln(x!)}{x\ln x}}dx$$
Edit: after rereading this I find that it is a little hard to understand, I had found that
$$n\approx\int_2^{p_n}{\frac{x\Psi(x+1)-\ln(x!)}{x\ln x}}dx$$
and I'm trying to use this to approximate $p_n$ from $n$.
*also $\Psi(x)$ is the digamma function

Note that $x\Psi (x + 1) - \ln (x!) = x +\mathcal{O}(\ln x)$ and thus your approximating function is ${\rm Li}(x) + \mathcal{O}(\ln x)$. The asymptotics of the inverse of ${\rm Li}(x)$ is well known (the error term is negligible) and leads to the known asymptotic series for $p_n$. Even under the Riemann hypothesis, your approximation for $\pi(x)$ is not better than the standard one.

@Gary I noticed that $x\Psi(x+1)-\ln(x!)=x+O(\ln x)$ while doing research on the digamma function since I didn't know much about it, after testing what I came up with and comparing it to Li($x$) it appeared to be slightly better than it, for values up to 1000 it would only be one or 2 off meanwhile Li would be 5-10 off.

That is because $\pi(x) <\text{Li}(x) $ until a very large number (Skewes' number) and your approximating function is $<\text{Li}(x) $. But once $\pi(x)>\text{Li}(x)$ your approximation becomes worse. There is an approximation which is better than yours. Look up the Gram series.

@Gary I was worried about that happening at Skewes' number so I'm assuming values where $\pi(x)<$Li($x$) which is predictable using the Reimann hypothesis which for my practical uses I am assuming is true.

$$I=\int{\frac{x\,\Psi(x+1)-\log(x!)}{x\,\log(x)}}\,dx$$
If you use Stirling approximation for the numerator
$$x\,\Psi(x+1)-\log(x!)=x-\frac 12 \log(x)+\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{e}{2\pi }}    \right)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\, \frac {a_n}{x^{2n+1}}$$ then
$$I=\text{li}(x)-\frac{1}{2}\log (x)+\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{e}{2\pi }}   \right) \log (\log (x))+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\,a_n\,\text{Ei}(-((2 n+1) \log (x)))$$
Using five terms in the summation, generating a table, a quick and dirty linear regressin gives for
$$J_n=\int_2^{p_n}{\frac{x\,\Psi(x+1)-\log(x!)}{x\,\log(x)}}\,dx = a+b\,n$$
With an adjusted $R^2=0.999970$, the results
$$\begin{array}{|llll}
\hline
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std.  Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 1.70668 & 0.101754 &    \{1.50700,1.90635\} \\
 b & 1.01022 & 0.000176 &    \{1.00988,1.01057\} \\
\end{array}$$
